# Xamarin Monotouch CustomCell is blank

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, custom-cell

I have the following CustomCell:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace Zurfers.Mobile.iOS
{
    public class CustomCell : UITableViewCell
    {
        UILabel headingLabel, subheadingLabel, priceLabel;
        UIImageView imageService;
        UIImageView star, star2, star3, star4, star5;
        public CustomCell (NSString cellId) : base (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellId)
        {
            imageService = new UIImageView();
            star   = new UIImageView();
            star2  = new UIImageView();
            star3  = new UIImageView();
            star4  = new UIImageView();
            star5  = new UIImageView();
            headingLabel = new UILabel(){
                Font = UIFont.FromName("Cochin-BoldItalic", 22f),
                TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB (127, 51, 0),
            };
            subheadingLabel = new UILabel(){
                Font = UIFont.FromName("Cochin-BoldItalic", 22f),
                TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB (127, 51, 0),
            };
            priceLabel = new UILabel(){
                Font = UIFont.FromName("Cochin-BoldItalic", 22f),
                TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB (127, 51, 0),
            };
        }

        public void UpdateCell (string title, string subtitle, string price, UIImage image)
        {
            imageService.Image = image;
            headingLabel.Text = title;
            subheadingLabel.Text = subtitle;
            priceLabel.Text = price;
        }

        public override void LayoutSubviews ()
        {
            base.LayoutSubviews ();
            imageService.Frame = new RectangleF(63, 5, 33, 33);
            headingLabel.Frame = new RectangleF(5, 4, 63, 25);
            subheadingLabel.Frame = new RectangleF(100, 18, 100, 20);
            priceLabel.Frame = new RectangleF(250, 18, 100, 20);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my TableSource:

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace Zurfers.Mobile.iOS
{
    public class HotelTableSource : UITableViewSource
    {

        string[] tableItems;
        NSString cellIdentifier = new NSString("TableCell");

        public HotelTableSource (string[] items)
        {
            tableItems = items;
        }
        public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)
        {
            return tableItems.Length;
        }

        public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            new UIAlertView("Row Selected", tableItems[indexPath.Row], null, "OK", null).Show();
            tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true); // normal iOS behaviour is to remove the blue highlight
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {

            CustomCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier) as CustomCell;
            if (cell == null)
                cell = new CustomCell(cellIdentifier);
            cell.UpdateCell(tableItems[indexPath.Row], tableItems[indexPath.Row], tableItems[indexPath.Row],
                            UIImage.FromFile (tableItems[indexPath.Row]) );
            return cell;


        }
    }
}
```

But when I run the app the TableView is empty. Each CustomCell has a value before I create the TableView.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cell not only should contains controls, they should be placed on it (or on it's `ContentView`). Call `AddSubview` for any controls, which you adding to your custom cell:

```cs
ImageService = new UIImageView();
AddSubview(ImageService);
```

---

If it doesn't help, try to use `UITableViewCell`'s default controls (`TextLabel`, `DetailTextLabel`, `ImageView`) to show some data. If data appears, there is still an issue in your custom `UITableViewCell` (wrong frames, empty texts), If not, issue is in `UITableViewSource` (empty data).